# WP the_posts() on single-cars.php get category link

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, categories, custom-taxonomy, wp-query

I have a custom post type called cars.
There is a taxonomy brands.

I have a template single-cars.php and I'd like to add a link to the brand page(The category). 
Assume I'm on the page of the post Passat 2013. The brand is Volkswagen. I'd like to show the permalink of the brand Volkswagen.

My setup:
functions.php

```
$labelsCars = array(
    'name' => 'Cars',
    'singular_name' => 'Car',
    'menu_name' => 'Cars',
    'add_new_item' => 'Add New Car',
    'edit_item' => 'Edit Car',
    'new_item' => 'New Car',
    'view_item' => 'View Car',
    'not_found' => 'No Cars Found'
);

$argsCars = array(
  'labels' => $labelsCars,
  'public' => true,
  'publicly_queryable' => true,
  'show_ui' => true, 
  'show_in_menu' => true, 
  'query_var' => true,
  'rewrite' => true,
  'capability_type' => 'post',
  'has_archive' => true, 
  'hierarchical' => false,
  'menu_position' => null,
  'supports' => array('title','editor','page-attributes','thumbnail'),
  'exclude_from_search' => true,
  'taxonomies' => array('brands')
); 
register_post_type('cars',$argsCars);

$labels = array(
  'name' => 'Brands',
  'singular_name' => 'Brand',
  'search_items' => 'Search Brands',
  'all_items' => 'All Brands',
  'edit_item' => 'Edit Brand', 
  'update_item' => 'Update Brand',
  'add_new_item' => 'Add New Brand',
  'new_item_name' => 'New Brand',
  'menu_name' => 'Brands'
);  

register_taxonomy('brands',array('cars'), array(
   'labels' => $labels, 
   'hierarchical' => true,
   'show_ui' => true,
   'query_var' => true,
   'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'brands' ),
   'show_in_nav_menus' => true
 ));
```

single-cars.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php $content = get_the_excerpt(); ?>
<?php the_content() ?>
<?php echo '<pre>'.print_r(get_the_category($post->ID), 1).'</pre>'; ?>
<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

The page single-cars.php shows an empty array, while the $post var is filled with data.

I've been searching through the docs and with Google and ofcourse also here, but I didn't find anything..

What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`get_the_category()` only works with the default taxonomy, per the [Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category); you probably need to use [`get_the_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms) instead.

So you'd replace your `get_the_category()` call with `get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'brands' );`, if I'm not mistaken.